# Using enum and getline

Tags: c++, enums, getline

I'm working on this assignment that wants us to enter student info (name, SSN, userID, and password) declared using enum.  Then it'll return those values entered and replace the SSN and password variables as 'X's.  So, for example, you enter in:

`John Doe, 123456789, JohnD89, doggosarebest`

It'll return :

`John Doe, XXXXXXXXX, JohnD89, XXXXXXXXXXXXX.`

I have no idea how to structure this, as the text examples offer nothing related to this.

I can make some sort of loop that'll return the SSN and password variables as X's, but we have to use `getline()` instead of `cin` to grab the input, and I get a million errors if I use `getline()` to snag more than one variable.

Comment: The technique is to use `getline` to read a string, put the string into an `istringstream` and then use `>>` to read as many varables are you need from the `istringstream`. There must be thousands of examples out there on the internet. Try google, or read your favourite C++ book.

Comment: Don't use `>>` for this, since the values (at least the 1st value, anyway) can contain spaces, as shown in the example above.  You can use `std::getline()` to read delimited values, just pass it a delimiter in its 3rd input parameter, in this case `','`.